# How to use reflection to go from array to a data structure in php

Tags: php, reflection

I read on php.net that the SplFixedArray has "The advantage is that it allows a faster array implementation" over regular arrays. Some how I also want to understand reflection. I cannot seem to get it to work:

```
$refDLL = new ReflectionClass( 'SplDoublyLinkedList' );
$method = $refDLL->getMethod( 'add' );
$keys = array_keys( $_GET );
$count = count( $keys );
$oIndex = 0;
while( $oIndex < $count )
{
    $method( // <-- this seems to be the point of failure
        $oIndex, 
        $_GET[$keys[$oIndex]] 
    );
    $oIndex++;
}
```

error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in 
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\objstr.php:26
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\objstr.php on line 26
```

Comment: what exactly is the error message you've encountered?

Comment: That code produces a different error for me - `Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Method add does not exist'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
$refDLL = new ReflectionMethod( 'SplDoublyLinkedList', 'add' );
$keys = array_keys( $_GET );
$count = count( $keys );
$oIndex = 0;
$sdll = new SplDoublyLinkedList();
while( $oIndex < $count )
{

    $refDLL->invoke( $sdll, 
        $oIndex, 
        $_GET[$keys[$oIndex]] 
    );
    $oIndex++;
}

$sdll->rewind();

while( $sdll->valid() )
{
    print_r( $sdll->key() ); echo '<br />';
    print_r( $sdll->current() ); echo '<br />';
    $sdll->next();
}
```

Query:

```
?zero=pZ0&one=pO1
```

Output:

```
0
pZ0
1
pO1
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done easier. Reflection getMethod() does not return closure but `ReflectionMethod` so when you getMethod() you  can invoke it

```
 $method = $refDLL->getMethod( 'add' );
 $method->invoke($sdll, $oIndex, $_GET[$keys[$oIndex]] );
```

Error comes because you try to invoke method as it was closure but it isn't'.

Edit:

Just change

```
$oIndex = 0;
$sdll = new SplDoublyLinkedList();
while( $oIndex < $count )
{
    $method( // <-- this seems to be the point of failure
        $oIndex, 
        $_GET[$keys[$oIndex]] 
    );
    $oIndex++;
}
```

to

```
$sdll = new SplDoublyLinkedList();

for ($oIndex = 0; $oIndex < $count; ++$oIndex )
{
    $method->invoke($sdll, $oIndex, $_GET[$keys[$oIndex]] );
}
```

Btw you use while loop the way that it could be easily replaced with for loop.

Comment: This is very unclear. Can you show a working example of the "getMethod" and "invoke"?

Comment: You are also right. $refDLL = new ReflectionClass( 'SplDoublyLinkedList' );
$method = $refDLL->getMethod( 'add' );
$keys = array_keys( $_GET );
$count = count( $keys );
$oIndex = 0;
$sdll = new SplDoublyLinkedList();
while( $oIndex < $count )
{
 $method->invoke( $sdll,
  $oIndex, 
  $_GET[$keys[$oIndex]] 
 );
 $oIndex++;
}

Comment: what's unclear? changing closure to invoking method on object?

Comment: The $refDLL was one object and $sdll was another object. It just took me a minute to figure out that they were the same object.